# Пьяная лавочка

Tags: фразеология

Когда о человеке говорят, что он сотворил что-то спьяну, иногда употребляют выражение (чаще с ироничным оттенком) "по пьяной лавочке". А о какой лавочке идет речь? О лавке, на которой сидят, или лавке - магазине? Но в обоих случаях, почему этот предмет пьяный и как это все вообще относится к выпившему человеку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С.И.Ожегов, Н.Ю.Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка.
лавочка, -и, ж.
1. см. лавка1-2 .
2. Небольшая скамейка. Л. у ворот.
**3. О незаконных, жульнических махинациях, а также о людях, участвующих в таких
махинациях (разг.).** Раскрыть, прикрыть чью-н. лавочку

Полагаю, что используется всё-таки значение, пришедшее их воровского мира. "По пьяной лавочке" значит, по делу, на которое решили идти по-пьяни, не подготовившись. Дело такое заведомо обречено на провал, вот "по пьяной лавочке" и происходят всяческие курьезы и неудачи. Либо разболтал что-то лишнее, либо упал и сломал себе что-нибудь...

Answer (score 4):

Позволю себе лишь немного раскрыть ответ предыдущего участника. "Мы всем классом ходили в кино"... "Вся школа присутствовала на соревнованиях"... " Город выстоял и не сдался врагу"... Мы часто называем группы людей так же, как и места, их объединяющие. Вот и в данном случае **лавочка** становится синонимом слову **компания**. "Привет вашей беседке от нашей лавочки!"))) На лавочке не редко распивались спиртные напитки, поэтому лавочка и подарила такое определение состоянию алкогольного опьянения, как **пьяная лавочка**. Мало вероятно, что сделали это представители воровского мира, скорей сторонние наблюдатели, ибо этот мир достаточно суров и там более приемлемы такие выражения: **по пьяни**, **по синьке**, а это словосочетание слишком мягкое.

Comment: @Сашка-дурак.Поддерживаю ваш ответ - здесь не "воровское" , а просто бытовое .

Comment: Спасибо вам.